# Selecting by row from pd.df.ix[] view?

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.5

Given the following, `multiIndex`ed `pd.DataFrame`:

```
Type                      p&l position    rolldate        value       vola  
Date       Symbol                                                           
2008-01-02 AC       1757.2168        1  1201132800   45588.9161   480.6781  
           AUD         0.0000        0  1205280000   59872.0044   542.8067  
           BAX       551.1540        2  1208736000  165621.7706   125.8527  
           BTP         0.0000        0          -1          NaN     0.0000  
           C         674.4908        2  1202342400   14407.1226   137.4325  
           CAC40       0.0000        0  1200441600   55565.0000   580.2757  
           CAD         0.0000        0  1205280000   68784.0414   593.7115  
           CC        422.1133        1  1202428800   14276.9608   197.4064  
           CGB       482.2597        1  1203638400   79655.5288   299.6622  
           CHF     -1216.9798       -1  1205280000   76431.4406   391.3853  
           CL          0.0000        0  1200355200   67824.0741  1268.3927  
           COIL        0.0000        0  1199750400   66612.2004  1088.8291  
           CT        296.1601        1  1202774400   23447.7124   239.7177  
           D         217.8649        1  1202688000   13201.2527   210.3416  
           DAX         0.0000        0  1205798400  200712.5000  1644.8412  
           DX        469.7712       -1  1205193600   51749.7277   215.9024  
           EMD         0.0000        0  1205366400   58135.8932   753.5315  
           ES          0.0000        0  1205366400   49649.3736   632.5416  
           ESTX50   -570.0000        1  1205798400   43780.0000   381.5206  
           EUR         0.0000        0  1205280000  125382.9657   605.9757  
           GBL     -1020.0000       -1  1204588800  114130.0000   355.3088  
           GBM      -730.0000       -1  1204588800  108670.0000   229.3634  
           GBP       -93.6138        1  1205280000   84095.0095   477.9144  
           GBS      -825.0000       -3  1204588800  103630.0000   100.1981  
           GBX         0.0000        0  1204588800   91280.0000   548.0709  
           GC          0.0000        0  1201219200   58551.1983   678.5194  
           GE        578.7037        2  1221523200  164760.3486   110.1067  
           GF        204.2484       -1  1203984000   36254.0850   261.8514
```

I'm trying to access a row' value by `Date`, `Symbol` and then `column` name. 
So far I have only gotten this far:

```
In [38]: df.ix['2008-01-02', 'AC']
Out[38]: 
       Type     
Value  benchmark             NaN
       cm           1.201824e+09
       cm_next      1.204330e+09
       margin                NaN
       nav                   NaN
       p&l          1.757217e+03
       position     1.000000e+00
       rolldate     1.201133e+09
       value        4.558892e+04
       vola         4.806781e+02
Name: (2008-01-02, AC), dtype: float64
```

It's close to what I want; However, I can't seem to able to figure out how to access the `Type` rows.

```
df[df.loc['2008-01-02', 'AC']]['p&l'] # raises a KeyError

In [39]: df.ix['2008-01-02', 'AC']['Value'] # Gets me closer, but not quite there
Out[39]: 
Type
benchmark             NaN
cm           1.201824e+09
cm_next      1.204330e+09
margin                NaN
nav                   NaN
p&l          1.757217e+03
position     1.000000e+00
rolldate     1.201133e+09
value        4.558892e+04
vola         4.806781e+02
Name: (2008-01-02, AC), dtype: float64

In [40]: df.ix['2008-01-02', 'AC']['Value']['p&l'] # raises another KeyError
```

I cannot rely on `DataFrame.head()` or `.tail()` or any other kind of numerical index, as I cannot be certain that the columns will always be in the same order, nor equal in number per run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) - see [docs - using slicers](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers):

```
print df
                         p&l  position    rolldate        value      vola
Date       Symbol                                                        
2008-01-02 AC      1757.2168         1  1201132800   45588.9161  480.6781
           AUD        0.0000         0  1205280000   59872.0044  542.8067
           BAX      551.1540         2  1208736000  165621.7706  125.8527
           BTP        0.0000         0          -1          NaN    0.0000
           C        674.4908         2  1202342400   14407.1226  137.4325
           CAC40      0.0000         0  1200441600   55565.0000  580.2757
           CAD        0.0000         0  1205280000   68784.0414  593.7115
           CC       422.1133         1  1202428800   14276.9608  197.4064
           CGB      482.2597         1  1203638400   79655.5288  299.6622

idx = pd.IndexSlice
print df.loc[idx['2008-01-02', 'AC'], idx['rolldate']]
1201132800.0
```

EDIT:

If `Multiindex` is in columns too, add first level - `Value`:

```
print df
Type                  Value                                            
Date                    p&l position    rolldate        value      vola
2008-01-02 AC     1757.2168        1  1201132800   45588.9161  480.6781
           AUD       0.0000        0  1205280000   59872.0044  542.8067
           BAX     551.1540        2  1208736000  165621.7706  125.8527
           BTP       0.0000        0          -1          NaN    0.0000
           C       674.4908        2  1202342400   14407.1226  137.4325
           CAC40     0.0000        0  1200441600   55565.0000  580.2757
           CAD       0.0000        0  1205280000   68784.0414  593.7115
           CC      422.1133        1  1202428800   14276.9608  197.4064
           CGB     482.2597        1  1203638400   79655.5288  299.6622


idx = pd.IndexSlice
print df.loc[idx['2008-01-02', 'AC'], idx['Value','rolldate']]
1201132800.0
```

Comment: `df.loc[idx['2008-01-02', 'AC'], idx['rolldate']]` raises an `KeyError` for me: `'the label [rolldate] is not in the [index]'`

Comment: What is `print df.columns` ? Is it list?

Comment: It's a `MultiIndex` - `MultiIndex(levels=[['Value'], ['benchmark', 'cm', 'cm_next', 'margin', 'nav', 'p&l', 'position', 'rolldate', 'value', 'vola']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]],
           names=[None, 'Type'])`